# Laravel use AJAX to append view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am just wondering how I can append a view within Laravel to my page using AJAX.

So when I didn't use Laravel I would have just done something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your.html",
    success: function (data) { $('body').append(data); },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

That would have then appended my html file to the current page. I am just wondering what is the cleanest way to do this with a Laravel View?

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that the View in question would be a html form. Nothing resource heavy.

Comment: To discuess the cleanest way to do this we would need to know why you want to append a view using ajax. There might be other options.

Comment: If it not resource heavy or anything, why do you append it using ajax and not via include using blade? And afterwards you fade it in when needed

Comment: Because I am planning on adding up to 5 extra forms in the future I thought that this might have been the best way to do it, I could do that however I don't want to end up cluttering my HTML on the page.

Comment: If you want to add extra forms you should use jquery to clone your form elements instead of ajax to request the same form again. This will be faster & will not require an additional request to your server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the laravel you goes like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get-form",
    success: function (data) { $('body').append(data); },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

Now in your `routes.php` you define:

```
Route::get('get-form', function() {
    return view('form');
});
```

And your view file let's say: `form.blade.php`:

```
<form action="...">
   (...) // here goes form
</form>
```

This should create an ajax request/response relation on the page. Each time you call ajax request new form will be rendered into `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have your form hardcoded but hidden in html (could also be included via blade)

```
<div id="my-hidden-form" style="display:none;">
   <form ...>
       <!-- form goes here -->
   </form>
</div>

<div id="my-forms"></div>
```

Then you could simply clone your hidden form to create new ones

```
$( "#my-hidden-form form" ).clone().appendTo( "#my-forms" );
```

Without knowing further details it's still hard to tell if this matches all your requirements. However, it will dynamically add forms (as you needed) and in addition it will not require an ajax call or mess up your html.

Using blade to include the form this will be even more structured.